# Convert String to Hash

Tags: ruby, hash

Im wondering if there is a better way of converting a string to a Hash.
My String will always look exactly the same regarding the structure. 
Here is an example:

```
string = "range:12\ntype:default\n"

@settings = Hash[
  *string.downcase
  .split("\n")
  .map{|s| [s.split(":")[0].to_sym, s.split(":")[1]]}
  .flatten
]

p @settings
# => {:range=>"12", :type=>"default"}
```

This does what it should do and I have no problems with this.
But it is extremely unreadable and I hope that there are some refactoring options for my code.

Comment: Why won't you add spaces before values and make it YAML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `String.scan` to search for key-value pairs in the string and then convert the resulting array of arrays to a hash by simply calling `to_h`:

```
string.scan(/(.+):(.+)\n/).to_h
#=> {"range"=>"12", "type"=>"default"}
```

If you really need the symbol keys, you can use `Array#map` before converting to a hash:

```
string.scan(/(.+):(.+)\n/).map {|k,v| [k.to_sym, v]}.to_h
#=> {:range=>"12", :type=>"default"}
```

If you're using Rails, there's already the built in method `Hash#symbolize_keys`:

```
string.scan(/(.+):(.+)\n/).to_h.symbolize_keys
#=> {:range=>"12", :type=>"default"}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Hash[*string.split(/[:\n]/)]
# => {"range"=>"12", "type"=>"default"}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you had spaces before your values:

```
string = "range: 12\ntype: default\n"
```

This string would be correct YAML, so you could parse it with Ruby `yaml` library:

```
require 'yaml'
string = "range: 12\ntype: default\n"
@settings = YAML.load(string)
# => {"range"=>12, "type"=>"default"}
```

So I suggest modifying your settings format a little bit, if you can do it.

Comment: Of all the answers, this is the most robust way to go about the bigger problem of storing key-value pairs in a text file. I think looking behind the question this way makes the difference between a good and a great answer. +1

Comment: This is really nice, but I cant use yaml

Answer (score 3):

This would work:

```
string = "range:12\ntype:default\n"

string.split("\n").each_with_object({}) { |s, h|
  k, v = s.split(':')
  h[k.to_sym] = v
}
#=> {:range=>"12", :type=>"default"}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Hash::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) can handle array of arrays:

```
@settings = Hash[
  string.split("\n")
  .map { |s| s = s.split(":"); [s[0].to_sym, s[1]] }
]
```